# How to use Coinpayments API in node js

Tags: node.js, api, express, coinpayments-api

am trying to integrate coinpayments into my site am using express js to run it i have gone through the npm docs but it still seems unclear to me and i have tried running some code and still nothing shows up. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
var express           = require("express"),
      app                 = express(),
      coinpayments = require("coinpayments"),
      bodyparser      = require("body-parser")

      app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
var Coinpayments = require('coinpayments');
var client = new Coinpayments({
      key: kfjdkjfkdfkf00d00,
      secret: 009093403440349,
});

client.getBasicInfo(function(error,result){
    if(error){
        console.log(error)
    } else{
        console.log(result)
    }
})
```

**it throws up error in my command line**

```
sniperfillipo:~/workspace/bitcointest/main $ node crypto.js 
/home/ubuntu/workspace/bitcointest/main/node_modules/coinpayments/lib/index.js:28
            throw new Error('Missing public key and/or secret');
            ^

Error: Missing public key and/or secret
    at new CoinPayments (/home/ubuntu/workspace/bitcointest/main/node_modules/coinpayments/lib/index.js:28:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/bitcointest/main/crypto.js:235:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:504:3
```

Am new to this don't really know for sure how things work

Comment: You're trying to use variables that don't even exist. It would be helpful if you post the exact error you are getting.

Comment: @FranciscoMateo I already updated my question. It throws up an error in my command line missing public key or secret. :) for replying

Answer (score 1):

The issue is this section here:

```
var client = new Coinpayments({
      key: kfjdkjfkdfkf00d00,   // <-- this line
      secret: 009093403440349,
});
```

What is `kfjdkjfkdfkf00d00`? It is neither a`String` nor a `Number`. It is an undeclared variable.

So you are passing an undeclared variable into the constructor of `Coinpayments` which takes on the value of `undefined` judging from the error message you provided.

So your actual constructor looks like:

```
var client = new Coinpayments({
      key: undefined,
      secret: 009093403440349,
});
```

In other words, you need to define your `key` value.

Comment: yeah your answer was useful but the api key that  they give is  a combination of both number and letters maybe you should have a look at their docs (https://www.npmjs.com/package/coinpayments). i cant show my keys here maybe you can send me your email to chat you up, help keeping here dry :) for replying @FranciscoMateo

Comment: Then it's a string value and so should be `"kfjdkjfkdfkf00d00"` not `kfjdkjfkdfkf00d00`